# Github 404 on Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api

I'm trying to add github auth to my rails application but I've come across a 404 when the user tries to sign in. It is not giving me any details on the error, the url looks like this on click:

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&state=719b0b1ebfa18c154c14cb8481044d23a67b9535a5888d46

The log states the following:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/github" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-06 14:56:40 +0000
I, [2013-12-06T14:56:40.382510 #581]  INFO -- omniauth: (github) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/github" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-06 14:56:40 +0000
I, [2013-12-06T14:56:40.473525 #581]  INFO -- omniauth: (github) Request phase initiated.
```

Where could this be going wrong, I'm new to the github API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you're getting a 404 error is that you're not setting the `client_id` query parameter. You should [create an OAuth Application](https://github.com/settings/applications/new) in your settings and use the `client_id` you get there.

So, the URL should look something like this:

`https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=a8a7ab5b5b4c3c21c&...`